# Is it possible to get the path of a file in the memeory card using J2me?

Tags: java-me

How can I get the path of a file or the current working directory using J2ME?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "current working directory" in J2ME, what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah its possible. Use the following code,

```
 Enumeration drives = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
  System.out.println("The valid roots found are: ");
  while(drives.hasMoreElements()) {
     String root = (String) drives.nextElement();
     System.out.println("\t"+root);
  }
```

For your more information look on this article, [Getting Started with the FileConnection APIs.](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/)

Comment: That lists the roots, not sure that answers his question though.